# How can I convert PDF to JPG with at least 3000 pixels on the longest axis (keeping aspect ratio)?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I tried:

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -g3000x3000 -dPDFFitPage -dUseCropBox -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=%d.jpg RUG01-002101562-2014-2_2014_0001_AC.pdf -c quit`

But this results in JPG images exactly 3000 by 3000 in size, ignoring the aspect ratio of the pages in the original PDF file.

Comment: Have you tried Imagemagick's "convert"?

Comment: -g specifically sets a fixed media, 3000 pixels by 300 pixels. It is possible to do things differently, but its not obvious what your requirements are. If you simply change the resolution then you'll get a JPEG of a different size, and since the CropBox is unchanged, the aspect ratio will also be unchanged. It is possible to determine the CropBox of a PDF file in advance and set the media size yourself, but you would need to do a bit of PostScript programming to avoid the media size reset that the PDF interpreter does.